# C# Two Way Binding Loop

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

Coming from a Java Background i ran into a synchronizing problem with the Two Way Binding mechanism. I have a property which is bound to a selectitem on a combobox.

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding car.hp, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

On the OnSelectionChanged Event i trigger a long time running command.

```
private void async() { 
    ...
    await longtermjob();
    ...
}
```

This works everything so far. But if i change the combobox selection quickly while the command has not been finished, I run into a infinite loop. The Selected Item keeps on changing between the two values. Any ideas how this can happen? How can i make sure the Binding is threadsafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the value of the bound property in the event without a stop condition, the data changing will continue to cause the `OnSelectionChanged` to fire depending on how you're changing the data. If you add a boolean flag that checks to see if the async call is underway already, you shouldn't encounter this problem. Further, I'd also suggest you consider disabling the control temporarily.

Edit/here's the solution:

```
private bool requestInProcess { get; set; }

private void async() { 
    if (!requestInProcess) { 
        requestInProcess = true;
        await longtermjob();
        requestInProcess = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: He could update boolean flag using callback once the current thread finish the task.

Comment: That's what's happening with `await`, but it's allowing multiple requests to be queued and started, which causes more ... .

Comment: Thank you! Adding a condition fixes the problem!

Comment: @Sonic - I added the code you wanted to add to my answer, but it had been rejected as an invalid edit.